# script file, wait function until end of generation files

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a script file (batch file) which generate three files in a specific folder. Then i have a ps1 file which copy / move the generated files to another server / folders. Separately, everything is working properly

I'd like if it's possible to merge this, and have a wait function between the two scripts. In fact launching the copy / move ps1 function, only when the three files was correctly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes:

- that the files are created and written *in full* in a *single operation*.
- that it is the appearance of a `*.zip` file that signals that all files of interest have been created (though they may still in the process of being written to), as you've indicated in a later comment.

```
$inFolder = '.' # set to the folder of interest.
$outFolder = './out' # ditto

Write-Verbose -vb 'Waiting for a *.zip file to appear...'
while (-not (Test-Path "$inFolder/*.zip")) { Start-Sleep 1 }

# Get a list of all files.
$files = Get-ChildItem -File $inFolder

Write-Verbose -vb 'Waiting for all files to be written completely...'
$files | ForEach-Object {
  do {
    # Infer from the ability to obtain an exclusive lock that the file has
    # has been written in its entirety.
    try { [IO.File]::Open($_.FullName, 'Open', 'Read', 'None').Dispose(); return } 
    catch { Start-Sleep 1 }
  } while ($true)
}

# Move the files elsewhere
Write-Verbose -vb 'Moving...'
$files | Move-Item -Destination $outFolder -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the last command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: My pleasure, @keupon17; thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

```
param(
    [String]$sourceDirectory = "c:\tmp\001",
    [String]$destDirectory = "c:\tmp\001"
)
Get-ChildItem $sourceDirectory | ? {
    #this step wait while locks free
    [bool]$flag
    while (!$flag) {
        try {
            $FileStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($_,'Open','Write')
            $FileStream.Close()
            $FileStream.Dispose()
            $flag = $true
        }
        catch{
            Start-ScheduledTask -s 1
            $null
        }
    }
    $true
} | Copy-Item -Destination $destDirectory
```